# how to get specific item just from user id to show at view

Tags: php, laravel

this is my current code

```
    $products=Product::all();
    return view('user.products.index', compact('products'));
```

this code return all the product to the view.
how to return only the login user's uploaded product to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have made relationship between the user's table and the product table by using foreign key or you are saving linking user's product with his id, It can be possible to show in this way-

```
use Auth;
Product::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

OR if you are using guard then call in this way--

```
use Auth;
Product::where('user_id', Auth::guard('guard_name')->id())->get();
```

It will return the array of all the products associated with the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `where()`:

```
Product::where('user_id', auth()->id)->get();
```

Or by using relationship:

```
auth()->user()->products()->get();
```

Or you can use lazy eager loading:

```
auth()->user()->load('products');
```